# Highcharts legend not showing series names

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I'm working on a simple project, and I'm trying to create a chart. Everything works perfectly except the fact that the legend is not showing the series name. This is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/emfuentes27/xajgowq1/).

HTML:

```
<div id="container" style="height: 400px"></div>
```

Code:

```
var myData = [{
 "name": "Beginning Farmer",
 "y": 1,
 "color": "#FAD252"
 }, {
 "name": "Organic",
 "y": 1,
 "color": "#B5C442"
 }, {
 "name": "Whole Farm",
 "y": 2,
 "color": "#EB2F65"
 }];

$(function() {
 $('#container').highcharts({
chart: {
  type: 'column'
},

xAxis: {
  categories: myData[0]
},

series: [{
  data: myData,
}]
});
});
```

[image]

What am I missing here? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually all I needed to do was to change the format of the object array myData to:

```
var myData = [{
"name": "Beginning Farmer",
"data": [1],
"color": "#FD31B4"
}, {
"name": "Organic",
"data": [1],
"color": "#A7DC7B"
}, {
"name": "Whole Farm",
"data": [2],
"color": "#67ABDA"
}];
```

And then:

In the `series` option, just change it to:

```
series: myData,
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

To set that value in the legend each series needs a `name` property:

```
series: [{
    name: 'Foo',
    data: myData,
}]
```

[**Updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/xajgowq1/4/)